# Save data to DB from tinymce

Tags: asp.net

I am using an ASP.NET application.In the page using tinymce text editor as the textarea.
So i want to know how we can SAVE data to db from this textarea content.

How to get the value from this text areat to a field.Please explain the details

Thanks
Sreyas MN

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tinymce` to mask your textarea, so in another words you dont have to do anything extra except to call the tinymce on page load (client side):

`tinymce` client side code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        });
    </script>
```

Your text area:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbMain" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" Columns="100"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in code behind you would have refernce to txbMain. so `txbMain.Text` would get you the content of the textarea.